# Three.js how to output to an existing canvas

Tags: canvas, three.js

```
     <canvas> id="topCanvas"</canvas>
     <script type="module">
     import * as THREE from '../../three.js-master/build/three.module.js';
     const canvasRef = document.getElementById("topCanvas");
     
     const aR = 16/11; // Aspect Ratio
     const cF = 0.9;
     const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvasRef, alpha: true});
```

I have the above code as part of an html page. The dimensions etc and canvas background are set and the canvas appears. BUT the subsequent drawing to the canvas does not occur and the console error shows as '_canvas is nul' in WebGLRenderer. Since this method of outputting to an existing canvas is recommended in several answers to similar queries, I am stuck. If I don't declare a 'canvas' then a default canvas is used and all my output goes to this quite as it should.